# Highlight, textcolor, and boldface simultaneously

Tags: color, bold, highlighting

I would like some portion of the text to have all three features but it's not compiling. It works two at a time but not with all three.

```
\hl{\textbf{foo}}
\hl{\textcolor{red}{foo}}
\textbf{\textcolor{red}{foo}}
```

The above three work but this doesn't

```
\hl{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{foo}}}
```

I have tried all 6 combinations.. I think.

Thanks

Comment: That'll be pretty intense!  I hope it's a warning to *really* **not** do something ... like pushing that mysteriously unlabeled red button.

Comment: Could you turn your snippet into a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: I recommend seeing this link. It contains **some good examples** of different approaches. https://texblog.org/2015/05/20/using-colors-in-a-latex-document/

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Put `\hl{..}` inside.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\begin{document}
  \hl{foo}
  \hl{\textbf{foo}} 
  \textcolor{red}{foo}
  \textbf{\textcolor{red}{\hl{foo}}}
  \textcolor{red}{\textbf{\hl{foo}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And don't be afraid of getting  eye cancer :-)

Comment: @Daniel hehe, I won't color my words like this. :-)

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks! I guess I hadn't tried all 6 combinations.

Comment: how is this done for beamer?

Comment: Not sure why \hl command is not working for me. I was using with beamer.

Comment: You guys were not mentioning which *package* one should include, in order to have `\hl` working. (Or, `color, soul` is not working for Beamer.

Comment: This doesnot seems working for environments like theorems. Means couldnot highlight a theorem.

Comment: Help, please. I got an error. If I have a command defined with `\newcommand` inside the `\hl` command, it says there is an extra `}` on the new command.

Comment: The `soul` package is not compatible with UTF-8 encoding use the `color` package.

Comment: For `beamer` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/460764/152568

Comment: @Daniel, I get eye cancer every time I use Latex...

Comment: [soulutf8](https://ctan.org/pkg/soulutf8) should be used for non-English texts

Answer (score 95):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
~\\
\colorbox{pink}{highlight}\\
\colorbox{green}{highlight}\\
\colorbox{yellow}{highlight}\\
\bfseries\colorbox{pink}{highlight + boldface}\\
\colorbox{green}{highlight + boldface}\\
\colorbox{yellow}{highlight + boldface}\\
\color{red}\colorbox{pink}{highlight  + boldface  + colored text}\\
\colorbox{green}{highlight  + boldface + colored text}\\
\colorbox{yellow}{highlight  + boldface  + colored text}\\
\color{red}\colorbox{pink}{\parbox{10cm}{
highlight  + boldface  + long long long  long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long colored text}}\\
\color{red}\colorbox{green}{\parbox{10cm}{
highlight  + boldface  + long long long  long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long colored text}}\\
\color{red}\colorbox{yellow}{\parbox{10cm}{
highlight  + boldface  + long long long  long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long colored text}}\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that you are building a box and hence your text is not broken at the end of line.

Comment: @yannis  I added an example of a long colored text.

Comment: I think "textcolor{}" should be mentioned.  "color{}" by itself is causing text that follows to change as well.

Comment: And how to highlight text over several lines in the middle of a paragraph? Thank you

Comment: But when you number the lines (with lineno for example) it labels whole box instead of individual lines. How can we solve this problem?

Comment: @YasinŞale Use `\hl` and `\sethlcolor` from the `soul` package instead, it can break highlighted text over mutliple lines.