# Highlight and Textcolor

Tags: color, highlighting

I was following [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141569/highlight-textcolor-and-boldface-simultaneously) to highlight and color the text. It worked fine except for a few exceptions.

First, I checked [SDrolet's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/319000/100384) in which the `\color` option didn't work for me. It colors the text until the end of the document instead of just coloring the words inside the enclosing braces. Then, I tried [user11232's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141572/100384) too. In this case, I am able to color the words inside the braces, but couldn't change the color of the text-box while using `\hl`.

Am I missing some packages or any options in packages?

Here is an example code using "xcolor" package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{color,soul}
\begin{document}
\section{Random Text}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Integer nibh magna, scelerisque sit amet gravida non. Suspendisse quis felis sed augue laoreet ultricies. \color{green}{Aliquam erat volutpat}. Aliquam a orci sit amet mauris rutrum volutpat id et turpis. Fusce tellus risus, sodales vitae augue sed, ullamcorper elementum nibh. Suspendisse sit amet ultricies leo. 
\end{enumerate}
\section{Random Text - 2}
\end{document}
```

and it's output.

[image: Using "xcolor" package]

Thank you in advance. Any help is much appreciated. :-)

Comment: Can you post a complete code example (including `\documentclass` and `\begin{document)` and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a parallel with, for example, how `\bfseries` and `\textbf{}` work, you should use

```
{\color{green} text to be colored, works until the group ends}. This 
is not colored anymore
```

or

```
text text \textcolor{green}{green text} default color text.
```

The first form will allow the color to extend between paragraphs, while the second one will throw an error.

Comment: Great!!! That fixed the problem. Thank you so much. :-)