# Highlight/color a part of text in block in beamer

Tags: beamer, highlighting, block

I am using beamer in Latex to make a presentation. I use a block for definition like:

```
 \begin{block}{P1}
 \justifying
  Some text here
 \end{block}
```

Let us say I wish to highlight a word "Some". By highlight, I mean something like which is performed by `\hl{text}`. However, `hl` does not work in a block in latex. So what should I do, if I want to highlight  text in block in beamer.

I don't want to change the color of text but I want to highlight it as shown in attached image. `alert` changes the text color. `hl` does not work in a block. So how should I do it?
[image]

Comment: Hello, did you consider using the \alert{text} command which colors your text using the colors defined by the beamer theme ?

Comment: @JCoulet  `alert` changes the text color, but I want too highlight it like a marker does. I have edited the question to show what exactly I want

Comment: Did that image come out of [Cool Text Highlighting in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5959/105447)? That's a neat one! Still, if `soul`'s `\hl` does not work in your case, most of those answers will also not work, for they rely on `soul`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can apply the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41693/36296 to your problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{soul}
\makeatletter
\let\HL\hl
\renewcommand\hl{%
  \let\set@color\beamerorig@set@color
  \let\reset@color\beamerorig@reset@color
  \HL}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \begin{block}{P1}
  Some \hl{text} here
 \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to change the color of highlighter, which is yellow here to some other color?

Comment: @ShiS Have a look into the documentation of the soul package http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/soul/soul.pdf

Comment: If possible, can you direct me to a specific page where it is given in this document

Comment: @ShiS start with the "Short introduction and common rules" section

Comment: @samcarter could you also briefly explain why `\hl{...}` does not do the job on its native format? (Out of curiosity ofc)

Comment: @Raaja I think a quote from the answer I link to explains it pretty good: "beamer redefines nearly anything" :)

Comment: @samcarter I will go through that link then ;)

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: @MdAmiruzzaman You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

If you can compile your document with lualatex, you could hightlight the text with the `lua-ul` package:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{luacolor}
\usepackage{lua-ul}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \begin{block}{P1}
  Some \highLight{text} here
 \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To highlight just a few words in `beamer` one can use `\colorbox{yellow}{text}`. This does *not* require extra packages or LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{P1}
        Some \colorbox{yellow}{text} here
    \end{block} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]