# Label sections of a report with a set of tags or coloured margins

Tags: formatting, margins, annotations

I am writing a report which is going to be structured in one way (i.e. the sections have been prescribed), but I need to make clear how various assessment criteria are met throughout the report - these criteria could be addressed in many different places in the report.

Are there any packages or recipes which would enable me to annotate my report with something clear and colourful so that I show at a glance where I am addressing the different criteria.  This could be per subsection or per paragraph.

I can see that `\marginpar{Citerion 2, Criterion 6}` could be a very basic way to go, but I was hoping for something prettier (akin to the "tags" you see on blog posts for instance).  It would be nice to be able to write something like:

```
\subsection{Seminars and Symposia}
\tag{Collaboration}
\tag{Communication}

Interesting things in this section...

\subsection{Training}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be easily achieved with `colorbox`.

As a reference, have a look at [Highlight, textcolor, and boldface simultaneously](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141569/highlight-textcolor-and-boldface-simultaneously)

If you always use the same color and want to save some keystrokes, I defined also a `\tag` command as you posted in your example:

```
\newcommand{\tag}[1]{\colorbox{green}{#1}}
```

Use the color you prefer of course!

Using `tcolorbox` you can achieve more fancy results (subsection 0.3).
See also here: [How to add a small rounded rectangle around a word inline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/458864/177)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\tag}[1]{\colorbox{green}{#1}}

\newtcbox{\fancytag}[1][red]{% see tcolorbox manual at page 16
    on line,
    arc          = 7pt,
    colback      = #1!10!white,
    colframe     = #1!50!black,
    before upper = {\rule[-3pt]{0pt}{10pt}},
    boxrule      = 1pt,
    boxsep       = 0pt,
    left         = 6pt,
    right        = 6pt,
    top          = 2pt,
    bottom       = 2pt
}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Seminars and Symposia}
\colorbox{green}{Collaboration}
\colorbox{green}{Communication}

\subsection{Training}
\tag{Collaboration}
\tag{Communication}

\subsection{More fancy solution}
\fancytag{Collaboration}
\fancytag{Communication}\\[\baselineskip]
Using \texttt{tcolorbox}.

\subsection{In the margins}
\marginpar{
    \fancytag{Collaboration}
    \fancytag{Communication}
}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

**One way** is to `\usepackage{soul}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[width=5.05cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{color,soul}

\begin{document}
\noindent\hl{Highlighting} text feels good.
You can draw attention of people to a \hl{word} or perhaps 
\hl{even a whole sentence that spans across multiple lines
in such a way that hyphenation etc. are not affected.}
\end{document}
```

**Alternatively** use soul and tikz combined together

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\defhighlighter}[3][]{%
  \tikzset{every highlighter/.style={color=#2, fill opacity=#3, #1}}%
}

\defhighlighter{yellow}{.5}

\newcommand{\highlight@DoHighlight}{
  \fill [ decoration = {random steps, amplitude=1pt, segment length=15pt}
        , outer sep = -15pt, inner sep = 0pt, decorate
        , every highlighter, this highlighter ]
        ($(begin highlight)+(0,8pt)$) rectangle ($(end highlight)+(0,-3pt)$) ;
}

\newcommand{\highlight@BeginHighlight}{
  \coordinate (begin highlight) at (0,0) ;
}

\newcommand{\highlight@EndHighlight}{
  \coordinate (end highlight) at (0,0) ;
}

\newdimen\highlight@previous
\newdimen\highlight@current

\DeclareRobustCommand*\highlight[1][]{%
  \tikzset{this highlighter/.style={#1}}%
  \SOUL@setup
  %
  \def\SOUL@preamble{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
      \highlight@BeginHighlight
      \highlight@EndHighlight
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
  %
  \def\SOUL@postamble{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
      \highlight@EndHighlight
      \highlight@DoHighlight
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
  %
  \def\SOUL@everyhyphen{%
    \discretionary{%
      \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@hyphkern
      \SOUL@sethyphenchar
      \tikz[overlay, remember picture] \highlight@EndHighlight ;%
    }{%
    }{%
      \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern
    }%
  }%
  %
  \def\SOUL@everyexhyphen##1{%
    \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@hyphkern
    \hbox{##1}%
    \discretionary{%
      \tikz[overlay, remember picture] \highlight@EndHighlight ;%
    }{%
    }{%
      \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern
    }%
  }%
  %
  \def\SOUL@everysyllable{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
      \path let \p0 = (begin highlight), \p1 = (0,0) in \pgfextra
        \global\highlight@previous=\y0
        \global\highlight@current =\y1
      \endpgfextra (0,0) ;
      \ifdim\highlight@current < \highlight@previous
        \highlight@DoHighlight
        \highlight@BeginHighlight
      \fi
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \the\SOUL@syllable
    \tikz[overlay, remember picture] \highlight@EndHighlight ;%
  }%
  \SOUL@
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  Lorem ipsum \highlight{dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis-icing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor} incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation \highlight[red]{ullamco $laboris$ nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit} in
voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.  Excepteur sint
occaecat \highlight[green, draw=blue]{cupidatat non proident,
suntinculpaquiofficiadeseruntmollitanimidestlaborum.
Loremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipisicingelitseddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlabore-etdoloremagnaaliqua.}
I suppose I could write some more text here.
\end{document}
```

Courtesy -- [Cool Text Highlighting in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/cool-text-highlighting-in-latex/6029#6029)

Comment: Thanks, but that's quite intrusive, I want the main text to be clean, hence the idea of a list of tags or a margin note.